# Questions about "how to toggle an element in HTML with JavaScript"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

**[2,475](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+toggle)** search results for posts containing `toggle` tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

**[3,640](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+hide+div)** search results for posts containing `hide div` tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

And there is no canonical answer, or auto-close for them.

So, while they are a simple way to farm reputation for many people, they are also polluting the list because, basically - creating a toggler is often the first thing people do in JavaScript.

And thus we are having lots of people asking this same question, over and over again. - needing to wait for somebody to answer, instead of just receiving a good link to FAQ.

Comment: Do you want to suggest a solution?

Comment: No. I point out to problem. Solution would be an answer, i guess ?

Comment: A canonical answer won't be easy to write without being quite generic: not only does it depend on the general markup used by each questioner, but also on the hierarchical relationship between the "toggler" and the "togglee" elements (sometimes they're the same, sometimes the toggler is an ancestor, a descendant or a sibling of the togglee).

Comment: @Frédéric: Even so, a half-dozen canonical variations is better than 6k snowflakes.

Comment: Same thing with "How do I center `{something}` in CSS?": I see that one pop up at least 3 times a day. [`4,383` search results for posts containing `center` tagged with
`css`.]
 My idea was going to be asking the question, and writing an epic (series of) post(s) that covers everything, and making it a CW. TODO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tags are *plagued* with this type of question.

I think the best course of action is to find a question that you think is useful and generic enough and start voting to close as a duplicate of that question.

Some other great examples of this problem in those tags:

- Why doesn't my `{insert (jQuery plugin || event handler) here}` work after I make an AJAX request and replace something on the page?
- How come when I return a value from a function that does an AJAX request it doesn't work?

There are probably many more. The other thing you can do is ask a high-quality question that you can direct people to after you get a good answer.

Comment: Or, "how do I get the value of the XML element" in C#/Java/C/C++/BASIC/LOGO/etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here would have to be to find the earliest questions that later questions would be
considered a duplicate of (as I understand, the "close as duplicate" flag reason is appropriate
only for closing as a duplicate of *earlier* questions).

After the earliest such questions are found, they should be either rewritten to make them more general,
or a canonical answer to the question added.